# SSL handshake error after Stack Overflow back on - anything related to SSL certification changed?

Tags: support, bug, https

I'm building a Stack Overflow app for BlackBerry10. Earlier today (Feb 16, 2014), Stack Overflow was down and after it came back up my app starts to have this issue.

My app works fine when it's in LTE, or home WiFi; however, it starts throwing SSL handshake errors under my company's work WiFi.
This never happened before. This makes me wonder if there's anything related to SSL certification that changed about Stack Overflow after it's back on?

If something I asked is confidential information, my apologies. However, it is quite important for me to understand what is happening.    Really appreciated for your understanding.